# In TypeScript, interface defines string, however returned type is string[]. How to properly access returned array?

Tags: arrays, typescript, graphicsmagick

I have observed a strange behavior of my node application using GraphicsMagick.

I would like to identify the number of pages in a pdf file. Therefore, I use "identify" which returns an object of type `gm.ImageInfo`. Then I "destructure" the returned object to obtain an array of strings that describe the format of my input file. The length should be the number of pages (which it actually is).

What strikes me is that `Format` inside the interface `gm.ImageInfo` is defined as string, however "identify" returns an array of strings (in case the input file consists of multiple pages). Still, I cannot formally define my "Format" variable as "string[]" because TypeScript tells me that a string cannot be assigned to an array of strings (which is obviously correct). How can I solve that conflict an obtain the actual array of strings returned by "identify"?

Here is the relevant extract of my code:

This works but I do not formally get an array of strings:

```ts
import gm from 'gm';

gm('test.pdf').identify((err: any, value: gm.ImageInfo) => {
  const { Format, ...rest }: gm.ImageInfo = value;
  console.log(Format);
  console.log(Format.length);
  if (err) {
    console.log('err');
  }
});
```

This does not work since TypeScript complains:

```ts
import gm from 'gm';

gm('test.pdf').identify((err: any, value: gm.ImageInfo) => {
  const { Format, ...rest }: { Format: string[] } = value;
  console.log(Format);
  console.log(Format.length);
  if (err) {
    console.log('err');
  }
});
```

`Format` typically contains something like this (for example if the input pdf contains 7 pages):

```json
[
  'PDF (Portable Document Format)',
  'PDF (Portable Document Format)',
  'PDF (Portable Document Format)',
  'PDF (Portable Document Format)',
  'PDF (Portable Document Format)',
  'PDF (Portable Document Format)',
  'PDF (Portable Document Format)'
]
```

This looks very much like an array. `Format.length` is 7 (= the number of pages). However, the type of `Format` is not `string[]`. How can I convert `Format` to a `string[]` to obtain an actual array?

Comment: Its really not clear what the issue is here. `Format` is a `string`. You can return a `string[]` by wrapping a `string` into an array -> `return [Format]`. Why are you trying it change the type of `Format` into something that it is clearly not?

Comment: I have added in the original post what `Format` typically contains to explain better what I am getting and what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: After trying many things I have come to the conclusion that the type of `Format` is not string despite its type definition. `identify` somehow "overrides" the type. The return value is actual an array of strings. Its type is object. I was able to get the actual array with the following code: `const actualArray: string[] = value.Format.toString().split(',');`.